# GIF animation get stuck when adding content to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, animated-gif

When adding large amount of content to dom (using jquery .html), loading gif animation get stuck.

Here is the [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zYDYU/1/). When clicking the button, before content is appended, the animation get stuck. Any solution? Thanks!!

javascript:

```
$('#spinner').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
$("input").click(function(){
    var html = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= 100000; i++){

        html += "this is " + i + "-----------";
    }
    $("#content").html(html);
    $("#spinner").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner">
</div>
<input type="button" value="clike me" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: the solution is not to add  a giant string to the dom

Comment: this doesn't lock up the animation for me... but yeah, looping through a function 100,000 times can cause browsers to choke...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely pushing the boundaries of what your machine can handle computationally, and 
as such your browser is *de-prioritizes* animating the GIF in order to handle appending new DOM data.

Try finding a different way to include the required data... perhaps just put it inside a JSON object.